# Using passenger to run both Rails 3.0 and Rails 3.1 app (using different rvm gemsets)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache2, passenger, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I just followed [these directions](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger) for installing a new rvm gemset and installing rails-3.1.0.rc2 on my local machine. At first I was getting a Passenger error saying the rake-0.9.2 gem could not be loaded, but I found [this](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger) reminding me to run "$ passenger-install-apache2-module". It installed fine prompted me to add the following to my Apache config file (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf):

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Users/robs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails-3.1/gems/passenger-3.0.7/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Users/robs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails-3.1/gems/passenger-3.0.7
PassengerRuby /Users/robs/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails-3.1/ruby
```

However, there are already three lines there from a different gemset:

```
LoadModule passenger_module /Users/robs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails-3.0/gems/passenger-3.0.7/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.so
PassengerRoot /Users/robs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails-3.0/gems/passenger-3.0.7
PassengerRuby /Users/robs/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails-3.0/ruby
```

If I leave both sets of lines there uncommented (the @rails-3.1 gemset's is last), and restart Apache, my Rails 3.0 app won't start. I find myself having to comment out the rails 3.1 gemset lines, restart Apache, and then run "$ rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails.3.0". If I want to run the Rails 3.1 app, I have to do the opposite.

Is there a way to have both be able to run at the same time without these extra steps?

Answer (score 0):

You could tell Passenger to use ruby 1.9.2 without a gemset, then in each of your apps run rvm use ruby-1.9.2-p180 and bundle install. This means your base ruby-1.9.2-p180 will have the gems for both applications, and bundler should handle limiting the gems available to your application.

End result:

1. ruby-1.9.2-p180 has gems for both apps
2. ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails-3.0 has gems for your 3.0 app
3. ruby-1.9.2-p180@rails-3.1 has gems for your 3.1 app
4. passenger is using ruby-1.9.2-p180
5. bundler should still limit the gems available to each application
6. both apps should work

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I ended up needing to also add the .rvmrc and config/setup_load_paths.rb files as explained in the linked article of @daekrist's answer.