# json gem install error on bundle install

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I try to do a bundle install I get the following json error. The bundle install does not complete. What gives?

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/.gitignore
An error occurred while installing json (1.7.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.5'` succeeds before bundling.

>>$ gem install json -v '1.7.5'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
Permission denied - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/.gitignore
```

EDIT: The sudo install command gives the following error:

```
>>$ sudo gem install json -v '1.7.5' 
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
sh: make: command not found


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.7.5/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550495/sh-make-command-not-found-when-running-bundle-after-adding-redcarpet-gem

Needed to upgrade command line tools after installing Mountain Lion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here: ["sh: make: command not found" when running "$ bundle" after adding redcarpet gem to Rails app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550495/sh-make-command-not-found-when-running-bundle-after-adding-redcarpet-gem) Needed to upgrade command line tools after installing Mountain Lion

Answer (score 4):

you need to install ruby1.8-dev and not just ruby1.8, you are missing the development headers.

if on OSX:

```
sudo install ruby1.8-dev
```

if on unix

```
sudo aptitude install ruby1.8-dev
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
```

go into your directory with rubygems source and run:
   `sudo ruby setup.rb`
after that run:

if on OSX:

```
sudo gem install json -v '1.7.5'
```

some unix system may need gem version command to work properly so you should run:

```
sudo gem1.8 install json -v '1.7.5'
```

Comment: Please re-edit your answer and remove text speak! This is an international english forum and you have a keyboard in front of you, use it! -1 for clearly lazy usage of english which may not be native to other non-english speaking people!

Comment: Better :) Happy holidays! :) \o/

Answer (score 1):

Try using this script

> sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local

Comment: did you install rvm using brew?

Comment: @Nick5a1 if you are using brew, what is the result of brew doctor

Comment: Know what you are doing if you are running this script. Might have unwanted consequences.